# Grid post page on Wordpress with Bootstrap, the_excerpt(); Problem

Tags: posts, loop, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page on WordPress with a grid which contains al my posts.

The grid works well until when I add the `the_excerpt();` for my post. The grid became a mess. The rows are not correct anymore.

This is what I have without `the_excerpt();`:

[image]

and this is what happens with `the_excerpt();`:

[image]

Here my code of page-post.php:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog-3 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div>

    <div class="container">

        <?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>

        <div class="row">

        <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

            <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 65px;">

            <p>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>

            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <p>Posted on <?php echo the_time('F jS, Y');?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> </p>

            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div><!-- col -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

         </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- container -->

        <div>
            <span><?php previous_posts_link(__('« Newer','example')) ?></span> <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older »','example')) ?></span>
        </div><!-- /.navigation -->

    <?php else: ?>

        <div id="post-404">

            <p><?php _e('None found.','example'); ?></p>

        </div><!-- /#post-404 -->

    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div><!-- /#content -->


<?php get_sidebar();
get_footer();?>
```

Comment: And your question is? Different height is a classical (bootstrap) grid problem, there are various approaches and answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590222/bootstrap-3-grid-with-different-height-in-each-item-is-it-solvable-using-only)

Comment: I want to add "the_excerpt();" but I want to maintain the grid system, 2 posts for every row.

Comment: Then you can use a `clearfix` as described in the link answer after every other post

Comment: I tried to add <div class="clearfix"></div> after </div><!-- col --> but I loose my grid, I get just one coloumn.

Answer (score 2):

The way I tackle this issue is by closing the row every *nth* column, like so. You basically collect the total number of posts in the current loop then at the end of each loop, increment `$i` and check whether it's divisible by two wholly (I'm rubbish at explaining this part).

Example: You could tweak this to `if ( $i % 3 == 0 )` if you were wanting rows of 3.

The example below can replace your entire container.

```
<div class="container">

    <?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>

    <?php 
    // Get total posts
    $total = $wp_query->post_count;

    // Set indicator to 0;
    $i = 0;
    ?>

    <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <?php if ( $i == 0 ) echo '<div class="row">'; ?>

        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 65px;">

        <p>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <p>Posted on <?php echo the_time('F jS, Y');?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> </p>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        </div><!-- col -->

        <?php $i++; ?>

        <?php
        // if we're at the end close the row
        if ( $i == $total ) { 
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            /** 
             * Perform modulus calculation to check whether $i / 2 is whole number
             * if true close row and open a new one
             */
            if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
                echo '</div><div class="row">';
            }
        }
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, that since Bootstrap 4, you may use **Cards columns**.

[You can check it here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)

> Cards can be organized into Masonry-like columns with just CSS by
>   wrapping them in `.card-columns`.

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">...</div>
  <div class="card">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```